# Are there any known criteria in order for $\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2-\sqrt{a_3+\sqrt{a_4-\sqrt{a_5+\ldots}}}}}$ to converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, radicals, nested-radicals

> ***Question:*** Let $a_n$ be a positive nonzero integer. Are there any known criteria in order for $$\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2-\sqrt{a_3+\sqrt{a_4-\sqrt{a_5+\ldots}}}}}$$ to converge ?

The motivation here was the initial question: Should we believe
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7-\sqrt{11+\ldots}}}}}$$ converges ? One could equally be curious about $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{6+\sqrt{8-\sqrt{10+\ldots}}}}}$$ and compare that to the [nested radical constant.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html) Also observe $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5+\ldots}}}}}$$ appears to be a ***complex number*** in stark contrast to the nested radical constant.  So I guess we should be concerned knowing if $\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2-\sqrt{a_3+\sqrt{a_4-\sqrt{a_5+\ldots}}}}}$ is a real number.

Note [Vijayaraghavan special case of Herschfeld's theorem on nested radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirukkannapuram_Vijayaraghavan). But this does not apply to alternating plus and minus. [Click here for Herschfeld's paper on nested radicals](http://www.pballew.net/1935Herschfeld.pdf)

Comment: Just to do a comment, not related  with your question: maybe you can to state different problems using different arithmetic functions. That I evoke is that *instead of your pattern of signs* $+,-,+,\ldots$ inside the nested radicals maybe it is interesting *do experiments with a computer with functions as the Möbius function or Liouville function* (for examples of $ \left\{ a_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty $). Isn't required a response of this comment, good day.

Answer (score 1):

A search for
"nested radical"
brings up this article
in mathworld:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadical.html

It only generally talks about
radicals where
all the signs are positive,
unlike your case.

It mentions a theorem
that mignt be relevant:

Herschfeld's convergence theorem:

If $0 < p < 1$
and all $x_i \ge 0$
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_0 +(x_1+(x_2+(...x_n^p)^p)^p)^p
$
exists if and only if
$ (x_n)^{p^n}$
is bounded.

The references are

Herschfeld, A. "On Infinite Radicals." Amer. Math. Monthly 42, 419-429, 1935.

Jones, D. J. "Continued Powers and a Sufficient Condition for Their Convergence." Math. Mag. 68, 387-392, 1995.

Your question involves
$p = \frac12$.

Comment: You are right. I misquoted the theorem. Thanks. Upvoted.